# When converting a .tif to a .jpg, I get the error "a generic error occurred in GDI+"

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, tiff

I'm trying to convert an image from .tif to .jpg and I'm running into an error:

A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I have no idea what the issue is and I'm having a hard time finding a solution online. Can someone help?

The error happens at `bmp.Save(jpegPaths[frame], ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

```
public static void ConvertTiffToJpeg(string tiffFile, string destinationDirectory)
            {
                using (Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(tiffFile))
                {
                    FrameDimension frameDimensions = new FrameDimension(
                        imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

                    // Gets the number of pages from the tiff image (if multipage) 
                    int frameNum = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions);
                    string[] jpegPaths = new string[frameNum];

                    for (int frame = 0; frame < frameNum; frame++)
                    {
                        // Selects one frame at a time and save as jpeg. 
                        imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frame);
                        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile))
                        {
                            jpegPaths[frame] = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.jpg",
                                //Path.GetDirectoryName(tiffFile),
                                destinationDirectory,
                                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tiffFile),
                                frame);

                            bmp.Save(jpegPaths[frame], ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is almost certainly happening because you're trying to save the image to a directory that doesn't exist.  You need to creating the directory if it doesn't exist already - `Bitmap.Save` won't do that automatically.  You should probably check `Directory.Exists` first to make sure you don't inadvertently overwrite files (prompt a user to overwrite or enter a new name?).

On top of that, the output of `jpegPaths[frame]`, as written, will look like `C:\temp\inputfile.jpg`, instead of `C:\temp\inputfile\1.jpg`,  Which is probably what you intended.  To fix this, you need to do this: `jpegPaths[frame] = String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}.jpg"`, or perhaps `"{0}\\{1}_{2}.jpg"` if you don't mean to use another subdirectory.  Again, make sure you create that `inputfile` directory before trying to use it.

Finally, it's unnecessary to load the `imageFile` frame into its own `Bitmap` - you could just call `imageFile.Save(jpegPaths[frame], ImageFormat.Jpeg)`, once you fix the other issues.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I think I found the issue. The String.Format is generating "C:\\00346A23.jpg" ...notice two backslashes. I'm not sure why this is happening. I want to save it in the C drive.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it by removing the backslashes. But I'm still running into the same error. This is what I have now:   jpegPaths[frame] = String.Format("{0}{1}.jpg",
                            destinationDirectory,
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tiffFile),
                            frame);

Comment: Does that output directory exist? You're just trying to save to a different directory.  You do want the two backslashes by the way, as they'll become a single backslash...  Try testing with a hard coded path at first to a directory you __know__ exists, then build from there. Or call Directory.CreateDirectory on each path before trying to save.

Comment: I got it. It was 2 things: 1 it was putting 2 back slashes and 2 the destination UNC path was wrong. We got it working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For anybody else who gets here, it's possible to corrupt an image file badly enough to yield this on read.

Comment: Yes, this error can happen pretty much if anything GDI can't really comprehend hapepns - invalid file format, trying to set invalid property for file format, trying to write to a directory that doesn't exist (this case)